# Converting Raw data to kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC format

Tags: ios, objective-c, avfoundation, core-audio, core-media

This question is little abstract.

I have some raw audio data coming from some source in the form of C `float **array`. I want to convert that data to `kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC` format. I am totally unaware of `Core Audio` frame work. Can some one guide me that which classes i should look at to do my work.

Answer (score 0):

You need to take a look on following functions: `AudioFileCreateWithURL()`, `AudioFileWriteBytes()` and `AudioFileClose()` from AudioToolbox framework. You also need to configure `AudioStreamBasicDescription` according to your input data and output format you need.